# Не отображается информация об объекте во View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Здравствуйте, я только начинаю изучать ASP.NET MVC. У меня проблема с отображением деталей владельца, отображается имя, фамилия, а вот сведения о машине не отображаются. Делала по примеру из сайта Майкрософт по изучению ASP.NET.
    public class Owner
    {

```
    public int OwnerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public int Experience { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CarOwner> CarOwners { get; set; }
}
 public class Car
{

    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Mark { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string YearofRelease { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CarOwner> CarOwners { get; set; }
}
 public class CarOwner
{


    public int CarOwnerID { get; set; }
    public int OwnerID { get; set; }
    public int CarID { get; set; }
    //public decimal? Grade { get; set; }
    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }
    public virtual Owner Owner { get; set; } 
}
  public class CarOwnersContext: DbContext
{
   public CarOwnersContext():base("CarOwnersContext")
    {

    }

        public DbSet<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CarOwner> CarOwners { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }

}
 public class CarOwnerInit:DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<CarOwnersContext> 
{
    protected override void Seed(CarOwnersContext context)
    {
        var owners = new List<Owner> 
        { 
            new Owner {Name="Sam", OwnerID=1, Surname="Lucky", Birthday=DateTime.Parse("1993-06-21"), Experience=3}, 
            new Owner { Name="Nick", Surname="May", Birthday=DateTime.Parse("1994-04-06"), Experience=5 } 

        };
        owners.ForEach(s => context.Owners.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var cars = new List<Car> 
        { 
            new Car {Model="gghguyg",CarID=2, Mark="ghffgy", Type="gghf", Price=7, YearofRelease="2001" }, 
            new Car {Model="gghguyg",CarID=4, Mark="ghffgy", Type="gghf", Price=77, YearofRelease="2011"  }

        };
        cars.ForEach(s => context.Cars.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var carowners = new List<CarOwner> 
        { 
            new CarOwner { OwnerID=1, CarID=2,CarOwnerID=1}, 
            new CarOwner { OwnerID=2, CarID=4,CarOwnerID=2 }

        };
        carowners.ForEach(s => context.CarOwners.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();
    } 
}
 Код для отображения подробностей о пользователе
   @model CarOwners.Models.Owner

   @{
   ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    }

    <h2>Details</h2>

     <div>
     <h4>Owner</h4>
      <hr />

      <dl class="dl-horizontal">
       <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
         </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Surname)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Surname)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Birthday)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Birthday)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Experience)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Experience)
    </dd>


    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CarOwners)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Course Title</th>
                <th>Grade</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model.CarOwners)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Car.Mark)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CarOwnerID)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </dd>




    </dl>

   </div>
   <p>
  @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.OwnerID }) |
  @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
  </p>
```

Comment: А можете показать код Controller для вашего View? Запустите под дебагом и посмотрите, какие элементы содержатся в коллекции CarOwners, может, она пустая?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще говоря, здесь нужно уточнить, какую версию **EF** Вы используете. Насколько я понял и контекста задачи, для Вас будет актуальным организовать отношение многие-ко-многим между вашими сущностями `Car` и `Owner`. В настоящий момент **EF** может взять на себя задачу по созданию так называемой промежуточной таблицы, которая будет эту связь (*M-M*) обеспечивать. Следовательно, класс `CarOwner` - уже лишний. Ваши модели будут выглядеть примерно так:

```
public class Owner
{
    public int OwnerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public int Experience { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Mark { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string YearofRelease { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
}
```

Поскольку коллекции помечены модификатором `virtual`, EF автоматически подтянет нужные объекты из других таблиц. При получении коллекции на экземпляре контекста вы получите готове объекты со всеми вложенными в них сущностями, в соответствии с отношениями, которые есть в БД. Раз уж используете CodeFirst, то используйте Migrations, это поможет следить за изменениями, которые вносятся в базу по мере изменения классов модели.

@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CarOwners)

Смысл этой строки лично мне, честно говоря, мало понятен. Неужели так написано в примере Microsoft?

В общем, после того, как добавите классы моделей и сгенерируете по ним базу, просто добавьте новый класс MVC-контроллера, к примеру:

```
public class OwnersController : Controller
{
    // GET: Owners
    public ActionResult Index(int id = 1)
    {
        var c = new CarOwnersContext();            

         return View(c.Owners.ToList().Single(o => o.OwnerID==id));

    }
}
```

Такой контроллер будет возвращать во View в качестве модели экземпляр типа `Owner` с указанным `id`.
Ну а в самом View отображайте то, что вы хотите видеть о машине текущего владельца, например, так:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Car.Type)
```

Comment: Когда я пытаюсь во View написать @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Car.Type) у меня ошибка.не видит Car. При создании базы сделала все как в коде выше только убрала все, что связано с классом CarOwner. Может я неправильно базу генерирую?

Comment: @Ksu, какую версию студии используете? Какая конкретно ошибка?

Comment: Я использую 13 версию студии. @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Car.Type) в этой строчке пишет does not contain definition for a Car and no extension method Car.